# Cycle 2 auto-height with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-cycle2, cycle2

I am using jQuery Cycle 2's auto-height feature (*data-cycle-auto-height=container*). This is great and it resizes the cycle wrapper to the height of each slide. However, I have a show/hide element inside one of my slides and the Cycle's height does not adapt when toggling this content.

Can I trigger the auto-height functionality on my show/hide href?

Answer (score 0):

I think it might work if you called the cycle-update-view function when ever your show / hide element is triggered.

```
elShowFunc(){ 
// Your Code Here
$('.YourCycle2Selector').cycle-update-view();
}
```